# how can a systemd controlled service distinguish between shutdown and reboot?

Tags: linux, rhel, systemd

I have a Linux process that runs on RHEL7 and is started by systemd.  When the process is stopped, I need to know if it is being stopped because of a system shutdown or reboot, and I need to be able to distinguish between the two.

Previously, under init on RHEL6, I was able to do this by looking at the pathname used to invoke my init script, and sent the process a different signal accordingly, i.e.:

```
case "$0" in 
    *rc0\.d*|*rc1\.d*)     #shutdown
    sig=USR1
    ;;
    *rc6\.d*)              #reboot
    sig=USR2
    ;;
    *)
    sig=TERM
    ;;
esac
```

This doesnt work with systemd...although my init script gets called at the right time, $0 is always the same (/etc/init.d/scriptname).

Is there some way under systemd to know if you are being called because of a system shutdown or reboot?  I'm happy to get rid of the init script and configure it as a systemd target instead, but from the documentation I can't see a way to do what I want.

Comment: You could try using `systemctl is-active reboot.target` and `systemctl is-active shutdown.target`

Comment: BTW, pre-systemd the typical way to figure out what's up is to invoke `runlevel` and look at the current runlevel printed (second letter/digit). That's equivalent to your rcN test, just a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CameronNemo's comment is on the right track. The special systemd targets are described in `man systemd.special` or http://linuxmanpages.net/manpages/fedora14/man7/systemd.special.7.html and the reboot target is active on a reboot. However, the shutdown target is active on any form of system termination, whether reboot or halt, so it doesn't help to discriminate. For other targets of interest see `man telinit`. I've had success with the following type of code:

```
/usr/bin/systemctl list-jobs | egrep -q 'shutdown.target.*start' && echo "shutting down" || echo "not shutting down"
/usr/bin/systemctl list-jobs | egrep -q 'reboot.target.*start' && echo "-> rebooting" || echo "-> not rebooting"
/usr/bin/systemctl list-jobs | egrep -q 'halt.target.*start' && echo "-> halting" || echo "-> not halting"
/usr/bin/systemctl list-jobs | egrep -q 'poweroff.target.*start' && echo "-> powering down" || echo "-> not powering down"
```

When shutting down the system it will always say "shutting down" and then depending on reboot or poweroff also "rebooting" or "powering down". `/sbin/halt` will result in a "halting". `shutdown -h now` converts into powering off when I try it, but that may depend on virtual vs. physical environment. I've tested in EC2 us-east using Fedora 20 (ami-21362b48) and CentOS7 (ami-96a818fe). If you come across a situation where this doesn't work please leave a comment and I'll try to fix!

Comment: Turn out `systemctl is-active ...` isn't reliable because the reboot.target can be in a waiting state when another shutdown unit runs. I'm now converging on `/usr/bin/systemctl list-jobs | egrep -q 'reboot.target.*start' && echo "rebooting" || echo "not rebooting"`. I will update the answer as soon as I have more clarity...

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thank you.